# Generic repository, function explanation / c#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, repository

I have found some interesting generic repository, but I can't figure out what the function does: PerformInclusions(includeProperties, query);

### Call to PerformInclusions,

```
public T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, string includeProperties)
        {
            try
            {
                IQueryable<T> query = IDbSet;
                query = PerformInclusions(includeProperties, query);
                return query.Single(where);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

### PerformInclusions

```
private static IQueryable<T> PerformInclusions(string includeProperties,
                                                       IQueryable<T> query)
        {
            if (includeProperties != null && includeProperties.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProperty);
                }
            }
            return query;
        }
```

I can use the single function without the second parameter.

```
Euser test = Adapter.EuserRepository.Single(u => u.EuserEmail.Equals(user.EuserEmail), "");
```

So i have 2 questions what does the function PerformInclusions() do and can someone give me an example what the includeproperties would be in the call to the single() function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: Yes I'm using EntityFramework

Comment: The whole purpose of the Repository pattern is to abstract away the data source. But you do not do that. Instead you expose implementation details (LINQ to SQL and Lazy loading) to the repository caller. Why do you use the repository pattern at all instead of using your ORM directly? As I do not see any benifit at all with your solution. Either create a correct repository implementation or simply stop using the pattern.

Comment: jgauffin can u give me an example that I should use as repository then? Would like to see the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Andrei says this is allowing you to use familiar EF include syntax to eager load navigation properties. The other alternative for nav property eager loading is via lambdas as below:

```
    public T GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var result = GetAll();
        if (includes.Any())
        {
            foreach (var include in includes)
            {
                result = result.Include(include);
            }
        }
        return result.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
```

If you have an entity with a navigation property as below:

```
public class Test{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public SomethingElse Thing {get;set;}
}
```

`_repo.Single(t => t.Id == 1, "");` OR `_repo.GetBy(t => t.Id == 1);`

will return an entity where `Thing` is null

`_repo.Single(t => t.Id == 1, "Thing");` OR `_repo.GetBy(t => t.Id == 1, t=>t.Thing);`

will return an entity with Thing populated via the foreign key

For some more details on what Navigation properties in EF are check out my blog http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first